# Using regex to empty contents of an if statement but retaining the outer curly braces only

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I would like to use regex with sed or perl or awk on
the following lines of code stored in a file, say, file.txt:

```
if(url == "https://abcd.com"){
if(p=123){System.out.println("url is https://....(OK?)); }
else{
//do nothing!
}
c=1;
}
```

and would like to empty the contents of the outer if statement and retain the curly braces so that the output is:-

```
if(url == "https://abcd.com"){}.
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please add samples of input and samples of output with CODE TAGS and let us know then? It will make your question more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how arbitrary the code is within the outer braces. For example, these are possibilities:

```
if (....) {
    c = '{';
    // this is a mismatched brace: {
}
```

To cope with such possibilities you'd probably require something that parses the language in question rather than a regex.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Except that comments don't have elegant formatting support.  :-/

Answer (score 0):

The following perl code would do the trick on your exemple

```
$/ = undef;
my $data = <>;
if( $data =~ /if\(url == \"https:\/\/abcd.com\"\)\{(.+)\}/ms ){
  $inside = $1 ;
  $data =~ s/\Q$inside\E//ms ;
}
print $data ;
```

However it would probably fail if there is more code containing curly braces at the end of you sample as it is looking for the last curly brace and extracting all between the targeted if statement and this last curly brace.